# How to flatten (not level) a concrete slab by shimming a subfloor

Tags: concrete, garage, subfloor

I will be working remotely permanently and have a another baby on the way so my current home office is  going to be a nursery.

I would like to convert a section of my garage into an office, but keep it something relatively easy to remove. The concrete slab in the garage is smooth, but it slopes about an inch over 4 ft towards the driveway. The total length of the office is 12' so I'd need to correct for 3" over the length. I'd was thinking of laying sleepers down with insulation and shim the sleepers to create a flat surface for flooring (laminate or vinyl). I don't want to use self-leveling compound.

Some questions:

Is this feasible?

Should I lay the sleepers over the rigid insulation or in-between?

Given its able to create this flat surface, how would I fasten the sleepers to the concrete? Would I be able to shim using short sections of 2x4? Or would i need to rip longer sections? (I don't have a table saw so that might be tricky)

Comment: What about a circular saw?

Comment: Not sure how go about making a cut like that safely.

Comment: With a circular saw confidence is important, if you try to back out of a mistake it'll try to get you.  But you have a stable footing, both hands firmly on the handles and are wearing apropriate PPE you're safe